# Listing the files stored in Google Drive by Javascript in HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

## Situation:

Hi all! I stored some spreadsheets in Google Drive and I want to list all the files (with hyperlink) in an HTML webpage with Javascript. By now, I studied Google API for many hours and found two methods to get the file list.

First, I used the following URL with an API key and it returns a JSON-like file list (see below). This method can easily get the file list without using OAuth 2.0. (I prefer using this method)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="MY_FOLDER_ID"+in+parents&key=MYAPIKEY
```

It returns the following information:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "xxxxx",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  },
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "xxxxxxxxx",
   "name": "xxxxx",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
  }
 ]
}
```

Second, I typed the following code (see below) to get file list successfully in the console log. This method requires the user to login Google Account for verification.

## Problem:

However, I have no idea how to display the received file list on an HTML webpage. May I know how to use the received JSON-like file list/log to list all files on an HTML webpage? Thank you.

## Code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("MY_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.drive.children.list({
      "folderId": "MY_FOLDER_ID"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "MY_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. How many files are there in your Google Drive? 2. About `list all files on an HTML webpage`, can you provide a sample result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

For example you have this html structure:

```
<table id="drive-file-list">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>Link</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And now you want to append some data there, for example:

*12345, Dogs and Cats, https://google.com*

In order to do this you can try this code:

```
let html = `
  <tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>Dogs and Cats</td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">Go to page</a></td>
  </tr>
`;
document.getElementById('drive-file-list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
```

Adapt it to your sample code now, by the way you can use [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get json response, f.e

```
let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q="MY_FOLDER_ID"+in+parents&key=MYAPIKEY';

fetch(url )
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {

    // Adapt it from here
    document.getElementById('drive-file-list').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
      <tr>
        <td>${data.files[0].id}</td>
        <td>${data.files[0].name}</td>
        <td><a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${data.files[0].id}">Go to page</a></td>
      </tr>
    `)

  });
```